# How to properly setup sys.excepthook

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, sys, keyboardinterrupt

I have written the following code to understand the sys.excepthook on a multiprocess environment. I am using python 3. I have created 2 processes which would print and wait for getting ctrl+c.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import multiprocessing
import sys
from time import sleep


class foo:
    def f(self, name):
        try:
            raise ValueError("test value error")
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
        print('hello', name)
        while True:
            pass


def myexcepthook(exctype, value, traceback):
    print("Value: {}".format(value))
    for p in multiprocessing.active_children():
        p.terminate()


def main(name):
    a = foo()
    a.f(name)

sys.excepthook = myexcepthook
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(2):
        p = Process(target=main, args=('bob', ))
        p.start()
```

I was expecting the following result when I press `ctrl+C`

```
python /home/test/test.py
test value error
hello bob
test value error
hello bob

Value: <KeyboardInterrupt>
```

But unfortunately, I got the following result.

```
/home/test/venvPython3/bin/python /home/test/test.py
test value error
hello bob
test value error
hello bob
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Process Process-1:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 28, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/test/test.py", line 26, in main
    a.f(name)
  File "/home/test/test.py", line 15, in f
    pass
KeyboardInterrupt
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/test/test.py", line 26, in main
    a.f(name)
  File "/home/test/test.py", line 15, in f
    pass
KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It will be a great help if somebody could point out what am I doing wrong. Also, please let me know how to get the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost did it.
At first, use `exctype` to print:

```
def myexcepthook(exctype, value, traceback):
    print("Value: {}".format(exctype))
    for p in multiprocessing.active_children():
        p.terminate()
```

And `join()` created processes, to prevent premature exit

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pr = []
    for i in range(2):
        p = Process(target=main, args=('bob', ))
        p.start()
        pr.append(p)
    for p in pr:
        p.join()
```

Comment: Hi @Alex Noname, Thank you so much, it worked, it was very helpful. I have one more doubt about the current output. When I hit ctrl+c it shows different outputs different times:
eg:
*One time:*
`test value error
hello bob
test value error
hello bob
Process Process-1:
Value: <class 'KeyboardInterrupt'>

Process finished with exit code 1`

*Next time:*
`test value error
hello bob
test value error
hello bob
Process Process-1:
Process Process-2:
Value: <class 'KeyboardInterrupt'>

Process finished with exit code 1`

It will be great if you could please tell me why so?

Comment: I think that it has something to do with propagation `SIGINT` to process group. You can read more here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149756/421375

Comment: Hi @Alex Noname, Thank you for the link. But in my code (In the question above), I am finding all active_children (Which is 2 processes) and terminate them. So, I should expect both Process-1 and Process-2 in output always, right?

Comment: I think they finish before you call `terminate()` because they get propagated SIGINT (Ctrl-C). Even if you remove the `terminate` statements, they will still finish due to the signal propagation

Comment: Thank you for the reply, It was helpful!